# How to use ListItem onPress to toggle target state

Tags: javascript, react-native, listitem, react-native-flatlist

I am displaying this set of data in `FlatList`.

```
state = {
  data: [
    {key: 'DE', title: 'DE', selected: true},
    {key: 'FR', title: 'FR', selected: true},
    {key: 'GB', title: 'GB', selected: false},
    {key: 'US', title: 'US', selected: false},
    {key: 'GE', title: 'GE', selected: true},
    {key: 'JP', title: 'JP', selected: true},
  ],
}
```

I want each item in the list to act like checkbox - pressing each item will toggle it's `selected` boolean.

I'm rendering the FlatList like so:

```
  <List containerStyle={{marginTop: 0}}>
    <FlatList
      data={this.state.data}
      keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
      renderItem={this._renderItem}
    />
  </List>
```

And my `_renderItem` uses `ListItem` from `react-native-elements`. If `selected` is true, a tick icon is shown:

```
_renderItem = ({item, index}) => (
  <ListItem
    title={item.title}
    avatar={getFlag(item.key)}
    onPress={this._onPressItem}
    rightIcon={{name: 'done'}}
    hideChevron={!item.selected}
  />
)
```

---

So the problem is, how can I write my `_onPressItem` function to have it toggle the `selected` of pressed item?

The demo code in [FlatList official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html) doesn't make sense to me:

```
_onPressItem = (id: string) => {
  // updater functions are preferred for transactional updates
  this.setState((state) => {
    // copy the map rather than modifying state.
    const selected = new Map(state.selected);
    selected.set(id, !selected.get(id)); // toggle
    return {selected};
  });
};
```

When I run that, the onPress event will give me an event object, and accessing its `target` key will return me some unique IDs which I have no idea how to use:

```
_onPressItem = e => {
  console.log(e.target) // => a unique ID number
                       // How can I find the pressed data item?
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the index to your `_onPressItem` function like that:

```
_renderItem = ({item, index}) => (
  <ListItem
    title={item.title}
    avatar={getFlag(item.key)}
    onPress={() => _onPressItem(item, index)}
    rightIcon={{name: 'done'}}
    hideChevron={!item.selected}
  />
)
```

Then you have to change your `_onPressItem` to:

```
_onPressItem = (item, index) => {
    // loop over your state data and create newStateArray 
    newState = this.state.data.map((val,i) => {
        if (index === i) {
            // change selected value of pressed entry
            return { ...val, selected: !val.selected }; 
        }
        //otherwise just return current value
        return val;
    }
    this.setState({ data: newState }); 
};
```